# is unix distro same as linux distro? or there is crucial difference?

Tags: arch-linux, distributions

i'm confused as to what is classified as Unix distro vs Linux distro. Or is it same?
aka ubuntu is both Linux and Unix distro and there is no difference?

Unix is much older than Linux , was created in 60-70s; Linux is based on Unix and showed up in 90s.

is ubuntu and Debian both Unix and Linux distros? or they stem from different things?

Comment: Is there even anything called a "Unix distribution"? What would one be?

Comment: @ilkkachu I believe "BSD" stands for "Berkley Software Distribution"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to the kernel they use.  In order for a distribution to be considered linux it must use the [linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux).

There is no unified "unix kernel" but the unix operating systems all in some way are traced back to the original unix source code (I'm sure there are exceptions to this that will be pointed out in the comments).

The term "unix" can mean different things as well.  For example "UNIX" is a trademark of the [open group](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) essentially referring to any operating system that conforms to the POSIX standard.  As such you can say linux *is* a UNIX (as long as they conform to the POSIX standard and pay the licensing fee).

Generally however unix refers to an operating system that in some way derives from the original at&t unix source, where linux refers to a specific kernel and not really any operating system.

Comment: Although there is a bit of a *Ship of Theseus* problem in that some of the operating systems that are universally acknowledged to be "Unices" actually no longer contain a single line of code of the original Unix system.